# Sql Server permission for read-only user to prevent locks

Tags: sql-server, locking

In a SQL Server database, there is a table that has millions of records, that gets insert to and updated frequently with new data.

Now the client has requested that they write their own reports off this table.

I am very concerned about them not writing reports correctly and that they lock the table on a long running reports.

Can I give them credentials that cannot lock a table

I.e. Can only do dirty reads similar to `WITH (NOLOCK)`?

Comment: You can just *not* give them `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` permissions on that table - then they cannot do anything that requires exclusive locks....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force nolock hint for sql server logins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64208/how-to-force-nolock-hint-for-sql-server-logins)

Comment: Do you have a read replica? Can you change to snapshot isolation?

Comment: @marc_s Hi Mark. Thanks for the reply but after testing, I can still see my update being blocked by my long running query by a report user.  I gave the user the db_datareader permission

Comment: @WillA I won't be able to use the solution given. The questions are very similar though.

Comment: @gbn I probably can but have no idea what that is or how. I will look it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could create a view over the table in question and add `NOLOCK` to that query. Then give their user account read only access to the view rather than the base table?

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ReportingView
AS

SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3

FROM dbo.BASETABLE (NOLOCK)
```